# « C’est le livre que je te parle » : précurseurs de l'emploi en langue populaire etc. ?

Tags: oral, conjonctions, registre-familier, pronoms-relatifs

> Le pronom relatif [*que*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/que) a le plus souvent la fonction de complément
>   d’objet direct : *Les livres que vous m’avez offerts m’ont beaucoup
>   plu*. Mais il tend aujourd’hui, et c’est une grave faute, à se
>   substituer au pronom relatif complément du nom ou complément indirect
>   *dont*. Cette erreur est sans doute liée au fait que la conjonction de subordination homonyme [*que*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/que/65601/difficulte) est extrêmement fréquente en français. Il
>   convient donc de rappeler que le pronom relatif *que* ne doit être
>   employé que dans les cas voulus par la grammaire.
>  [...]
>
> [ Académie française, [*C’est le livre que je te parle*](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/cest-le-livre-que-je-te-parle) (emplois
>   fautifs), 7 avril 2016. ]

En fait le LBU14 (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. *Duculot*, 14<sup>e</sup>) parle de la tendance à remplacer en langue populaire n'importe quel pronom relatif par *que*. Encore davantage quand la relative est séparée de l'antécédent, dit-on (« *Je l'entends qu'elle bourdonne*. » J. Renard). On explique que dans ce cas c'est souvent un autre élément pronominal qui joue le rôle du pronom relatif dans la phrase alors que le *que* assume un rôle de simple subordination. (§717) De plus, on explique qu'avec certaines expressions composées d'un verbe et d'un objet direct où l'analyse s'avère plus difficile, la langue populaire ne reconnaît pas le complément et tente d'en ajouter un avec *que*, en particulier avec *avoir besoin* (« *Le calcul est de savoir ce que lui et sa mère ont besoin pour vivre*. » Un personnage dans l'oeuvre de Zola) (§279)

---

- Quel type de construction courante ou de tournure particulière avec *que*
  se démarque ou influencerait le plus le locuteur qui dit « *C’est le livre que je t’ai parlé* »(X) à l'oral ? En
  d'autres termes peut-on préciser l'explication de l'*Académie*, ou en étayer une autre, et l'appliquer à l'un de ses exemples, ou plus généralement à la situation dont elle traite.
- Ni *Renard* ni Zola ne sont vraiment des auteurs
  d'*aujourd'hui*. L'*Académie* décrit-elle une tendance différente de
  celle discutée au *LBU* ? Y a-t-il une mesure ; les [*ngram*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=que&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cque%3B%2Cc0) ([2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=que%20je%20t%E2%80%99ai%20parl%C3%A9&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cque%20je%20t%27ai%20parl%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0)) révèlent-ils quoi que ce soit ?

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûre de comprendre la question, mais en tout cas l'Académie est claire sur un point : remplacer n'importe quel pronom relatif par "que" est une erreur. Est-ce que ta question est de savoir pourquoi les gens font cette erreur ? ^^"

Comment: @Pwassonne _Pourquoi les gens font cette erreur_ oui. En fait ce qui les conditionne, et je trouve l'idée de la subordination de _que_ bien vaste pour y répondre. Il y a plein d'homonymes qui n'ont pas cet effet. Aussi pourquoi on dit _aujourd'hui_ alors qu'on aurait pu dire je sais pas, depuis un siècle+ etc. ? C'est une erreur que j'ai souvent assumée à l'oral, mais que je ne ferais pas à l'écrit, chez moi c'est un registre conscient. Mais comment la langue populaire tranche la grammaire etc. est peut-être révélateur d'un autre truc sur la langue en général. Je veux savoir. Merci.

Comment: OK, c'est trop compliqué pour moi alors. Je ne suis pas linguiste ni historienne donc je ne pourrai pas t'aider. Mais bonne chance pour trouver des réponses :)

Answer (score 4):

En quelque sorte, vous voulez savoir pourquoi le grand auteur Franck Ribéry (à moins que ce ne soit un grand footballeur?) a dit:

*"Le Touquet, c'est une ville que j'aime bien venir".*

Il semble en effet que dans son cas, il refuse non seulement la nécessité de distinguer si le verbe de la seconde proposition est transitif ou non (le choix entre *que* et *dont* selon que le complément d'objet est direct ou indirect) mais il juge suffisant de considérer tout type de complément comme étant d'objet direct (alors qu'ici il s'agit d'un circonstanciel de lieu). En somme, un complément est un complément, et sa nature n'a plus d'importance. C'est du moins ce que pense Ribéry...

Comment: Merci, donc une forme de simplification davantage qu'une confusion...

Comment: Pour que Ribéry pense ça, il faudrait déjà qu'il pense... (ok je sors)